# How to get item bound to control by repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have 'BasketControl' control inside of repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc:BasketControl runat="server" ID="ucBasket" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The list of BasketObject is bound the repeater DataSource property.

```
public class MyParentControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(!IsPostback) {
            rptItems.DataSource = ...; // List<BasketObject>
            rptItems.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access 'BasketObject' inside of BasketControl?
What I want is to have access to BasketObject inside of class BasketControl, for example inside of the 'Page_Load' method.

```
public class BasketControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // here I want access BasketObject
        BasketObject basket = .... as BasketObject;
    }
}
```

Should be simple, but can't find any tips in Google...

P.S. Should I handle 'OnItemDataBound' repeater event and assign data object to control? Or there is quicker/easier way?

Thanks

Comment: You want access to item after databinding?for example your item has a button and when click you want do some thing?or you want access that item in databinding ?

Comment: Enhanced question to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually how I handle those kind of things is by handling the `ItemDatabound` event.

So say you have this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc:BasketControl runat="server" ID="ucBasket" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code would look something like this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnInit(e);

    this.rptItems += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptItems_ItemDatabound);
}

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(!IsPostback) {
        rptItems.DataSource = ...; // List<BasketObject>
        rptItems.DataBind();
    }
}

void rptItems_ItemDatabound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    BasketControl ucBasket = e.Item.FindControl("ucBasket") as BasketControl;
    BasketObject basket = e.Item.DataItem as BasketObject;

    // Use datasource/databind, but you could just as easily use a property/method of BasketControl
    // Like so: ucBasket.LoadBasket(basket);
    ucBasket.DataSource = basket;
    ucBasket.DataBind();
}
```

Hope that's clear. Of course, you could also use `AutoEventWireup="true"` and put the name of the event handler in the markup of the Repeater. But the basic idea is still the same.

*EDIT* In response to your clarification, you're going to have to explicitly wire them up some how. There isn't an automatic way of doing it.

I would suggest exposing a `Basket` property on the `BasketControl`. Then you could do something like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Your WebApp Namespace Here" %>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc:BasketControl runat="server" ID="ucBasket" Basket='<%# (Basket)Container.DataItem %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And you wouldn't need to handle the `ItemDatabound` event. If there's another way of doing this, I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I know that approach but for now trying to find if there is another. Will make make question a little bit more clear.

Comment: Updated my answer with another alternative.

Comment: Ok, probably that is only an option, but inside of repeater (on the mrak-up page0) we have access to binding object (Container.DataItem). In WPF we also can use (If I remember correctly, something like DataItem, or so)... I'm looking for solution that doesn't require additional efforts to assign bound item to control.

Comment: There isn't one, as far as I know. You have to wire up your controls yourself.